# Can't write to ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop

I'm trying to automate installing new SSL certificates onto a Windows Server using powershell.  I have most of it done but I have a small issue.  When I try to update the Terminal Services SSL cert I keep getting an error and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

```
    $NewCert = Import-Certificate -FilePath $FileName -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
    $RDPInstance = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_TSGeneralSetting -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2\TerminalServices
    $RDPInstance.SSLCertificateSHA1Hash = $NewCert.Thumbprint
    Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $RDPInstance -Passthru
```

I took most of this code from Microsoft's site to be able to do this update but it throws the error:

```
    Set-CimInstance : Invalid parameter
    At line:1 char:1
    + Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $RDPInstance -Passthru
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Win32_TSGeneral...me = "RDP-Tcp"):CimInstance) [Set-CimInstance], CimException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041008,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.SetCimInstanceCommand
```

I have tried a few versions of the Set-CimInstance but all of them seem to throw the same Invalid parameter.

Comment: Make sure that imported certificate is in PFX form. I bet it isn't, thus without private key. As the result you can get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah!  I found the issue.  It turns out that some of the attributes are read-only so I would be able to put the entire instance back again and that is where it was failing.  I have changed it so it is now just updating the attribute SSLCertificateSHA1Hash.

`Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $RDPInstance -Property @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash=$Thumbprint} -PassThru`

Comment: This worked for me as well. Would you mind sharing the original link to the code from Microsoft's website that you were using?